# Mantel-Haenszel test for trend R

Tags: r, trend, metafor

I need to perform a meta-analysis of two studies with two variables of multiples levels of exposure
data1:

```
    CA  CO
0   405 457
1   101 108
2   22  16
3   6   5
4   0   1
```

data2:

```
    CA  CO
0   154 141
1   42  65
2   13  9
3   2   2
4   0   0
```

But I don't find the way to do it with `metafor` in R; anyone can help?
Thank you very much